# Converting uploaded images to PNG with PHP script

Tags: php, actionscript-3, upload

I've got an upload button I've made in Flash that links to a PHP script and I was wondering if there was any way I could convert all the images to PNGs as the user uploads them?  This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], 
          "Parts/userdata/" . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']))
    {
        switch ($_FILES['Filedata']['type']) {
            case ".jpg": case ".jpeg":
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
                imagepng($image, $_FILES['Filedata'] . 'png');
                imagedestroy($image);
                break;
            case "gif":
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
                imagepng($image, $_FILES['Filedata'] . 'png');
                imagedestroy($image);
                break;
            default:
               echo "PNG Given";
        }
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "ERROR";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are not missing something in `imagepng($image, $_FILES['Filedata'] . 'png');`? `$_FILES['Filedata']` is an array.

Comment: This is not really an ActionScript 3 question then, is it? Or are you looking for a way to create PNG's in AS3, before you send them to the server?

Comment: I'm trying to convert the image after its been uploaded to the server; the actionscript method of doing so was a bit too roundabout for me. So it isn't really an AS3 question, sorry!

Comment: Does just renaming the file name and extention work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at some of my code, I think that

```
imagepng($image, $_FILES['Filedata'] . 'png');
```

should read

```
imagepng($image, $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] . 'png');
```

Or something similar. You probably want to remove the extension using `basename` or something similar. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)